# MitmProxy. Traffic interception. Error 500

Tags: mitmproxy, burp

Experts, help.
Using mitmproxy, for android app I change the request body (just by 1 character) and get a 500 code.

Original:
"DeviceID":"aaaaaa1"
Modified:
"DeviceID":"aaaaaa2"

The value of DeviceID can be anything !

But when I change only the headers, everything is fine (code 200).
The mitmproxy certificate is installed.
I also get a 500 error through Burp Suite.
What could be the reason?